# How to do string subsitution on env var in makefile script

Tags: docker, makefile

I have a makefile with the following script:

```
build:
    DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --build-arg GITHUB_ACTOR=${GITHUB_ACTOR} --build-arg GITHUB_TOKEN=${GITHUB_TOKEN} -t ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/strick:${IMAGE_BRANCH}-${IMAGE_TAG} -t ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/strick:${IMAGE_BRANCH}-latest .
```

and I just realized that when `${IMAGE_BRANCH]` has a slash in it, like `feature/a-b-c` then the docker build step will fail. I'd like to create a new env var which replaces slashes in `IMAGE_BRANCH` with dashes.

I tried several variants including the following

```
build:
    CLEANED_IMAGE_BRANCH=$(echo ${IMAGE_BRANCH} | sed 's/\//-/g')
    DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --build-arg GITHUB_ACTOR=${GITHUB_ACTOR} --build-arg GITHUB_TOKEN=${GITHUB_TOKEN} -t ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/strick:${CLEANED_IMAGE_BRANCH}-${IMAGE_TAG} -t ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/strick:${CLEANED_IMAGE_BRANCH}-latest .
```

and they all seemed to fail because `CLEANED_IMAGE_BRANCH` ends up being an empty string.

```
 ❮❮❮ DOCKER_REGISTRY=docker IMAGE_BRANCH="a/b" IMAGE_TAG="lol" make build
CLEANED_IMAGE_BRANCH=
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --build-arg GITHUB_ACTOR= --build-arg GITHUB_TOKEN= -t docker/strick:-lol -t docker/strick:-latest .
invalid argument "docker/strick:-lol" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
See 'docker build --help'.
make: *** [build] Error 125
```

What's the correct way to perform string substitution in a makefile script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the [`subst` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html):

```
CLEANED_IMAGE_BRANCH=$(subst /,-,$(IMAGE_BRANCH))
```

If I run this `Makefile`:

```
GITHUB_ACTOR=someuser
GITHUB_TOKEN=token
DOCKER_REGISTRY=ghcr.io
IMAGE_BRANCH=feature/a-b-c
IMAGE_TAG=foo

CLEANED_IMAGE_BRANCH=$(subst /,-,$(IMAGE_BRANCH))

build:
    echo DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build \
            --build-arg GITHUB_ACTOR=${GITHUB_ACTOR} \
            --build-arg GITHUB_TOKEN=${GITHUB_TOKEN} \
            -t ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/strick:${CLEANED_IMAGE_BRANCH}-${IMAGE_TAG} \
            -t ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/strick:${CLEANED_IMAGE_BRANCH}-latest .
```

I get as output:

```
echo DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build \
        --build-arg GITHUB_ACTOR=someuser \
        --build-arg GITHUB_TOKEN=token \
        -t ghcr.io/strick:feature-a-b-c-foo \
        -t ghcr.io/strick:feature-a-b-c-latest .
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --build-arg GITHUB_ACTOR=someuser --build-arg GITHUB_TOKEN=token -t ghcr.io/strick:feature-a-b-c-foo -t ghcr.io/strick:feature-a-b-c-latest .
```

Answer (score 1):

First, when you want to pass a `$` to the shell you have to escape it from make, because `$` is special to make.

Second, every logical line in the recipe is run in a separate shell so if you want shell variables set in one line to be visible in another line you have to connect them via backslash.

```
build:
        CLEANED_IMAGE_BRANCH=$$(echo ${IMAGE_BRANCH} | sed 's/\//-/g') \
        DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --build-arg GITHUB_ACTOR=${GITHUB_ACTOR} --build-arg GITHUB_TOKEN=${GITHUB_TOKEN} -t ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/strick:${CLEANED_IMAGE_BRANCH}-${IMAGE_TAG} -t ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/strick:${CLEANED_IMAGE_BRANCH}-latest .
```

Of course using make functions is also a fine idea, as long as you're willing to commit (or have already committed) to requiring GNU make.